# How to get line and polygon points from OpenLayers 3 drawing

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am working on drawing points/segments/polygons on a map that uses OpenLayers 3. The first part I have done draws points, lines and polygons.  Now I am trying to retrieve the drawn coordinates in order to build them for other sessions.

I have been able to getting just coordinate for the point/image, but can't get coordinates for segment/polygon.  Any ideas or help?  I've included a JSfiddle below

```
https://jsfiddle.net/Lg8w71kv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`drawend`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.DrawEvent.html#event:drawend) event that is fired by the [`ol.interaction.Draw`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.Draw.html) object you created.  If you hook into it, you will get back the feature that has been drawn.  See the fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lg8w71kv/1/